# Cannot use FTP to download BT Notifications.apk for Android Watch

Tags: applications, apk, ftp, smartwatch

I bought Yuntab Bluetooth Smart Jogging Watch U8 from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00ZHPCXYY). The printed directions say to download an APK from an IP address with FTP:

```
thufir@doge:~/.bluetooth$ 
thufir@doge:~/.bluetooth$ ftp 120.24.66.245
Connected to 120.24.66.245.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (120.24.66.245:thufir): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
ftp> exit
221 Goodbye.
thufir@doge:~/.bluetooth$
```

The directions don't specify a user or password.

How do I get the app?

Comment: That's not an Android specific question. But usually, anonymous FTP either wants an email address as password, or uses "anonymous/ftp" or "ftp/ftp" as login. BTW: There're some "BTNotification" apps on playstore you might try. One of them probably even matches the package name (I had such an MTK watch in the past), but no guarantee it works with yours: com.bt.notification / com.ruanan.bt / com.along02.btnotification Also woth a try: [MediaTek SmartDevice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mtk.btnotification).

Answer (score 1):

Using Chinese products from unknown sellers has many problems, for your example the links to the APK don't work or inaccessible for "BT Notification.apk"

**P.S:** I think the manual sent with your device is not the correct one.

Try this [BT Notification.apk](https://mega.nz/#!zlAiVYBK!xCdt7QEhAiAbZsRz2ATa5POzO8NQO89xpj3_Cj2zdpM) maybe it will help you.