# NTP sync over USB for chinese watch?

Tags: usb, linux, usb-debugging, clock, date-and-time

Context:

I'm having [some difficulty](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167114/48164) locating a specific .apk to synchronize the time on a specific watch.

What are the challenges associated with running some type of [NTP sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/46162/48164) over USB between a very inexpensive watch and Linux?

Comment: Does it have to be via USB? Does the watch support Bluetooth network tethering?

Comment: No BT. that's the obstacle.  Not without some special app.